# Disable Selected options between similar dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, html-select

I have a set of drop down menus (HTML selects) which are populated with the same values from a mysql query. I would like that, as soon as I choose one option from a drop down, that option can't be selected in none of the rest (or appear disabled). Basically, this is what I have:

```
<form name="test" method="post" action="confirmSelection.php">
<select name="color1" id="color1">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM colors
        ORDER BY name";

$res = mysql_query($sql);       

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $res ) ) 
{                                               
?>
<option value="<?php echo ($row["id"]) ?>"> <?php echo( $row["name"] )?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
<select name="color2" id="color2">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM colors
        ORDER BY name";

$res = mysql_query($sql);       

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $res ) ) 
{                                               
?>
<option value="<?php echo ($row["id"]) ?>"> <?php echo( $row["name"] )?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
<select name="color3" id="color3">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM colors
        ORDER BY name";

$res = mysql_query($sql);       

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $res ) ) 
{                                               
?>
<option value="<?php echo ($row["id"]) ?>"> <?php echo( $row["name"] )?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Any idea? I guess it must be simple but I don't really know how to look for it (it was really hard for me to find a proper title for this consult...).

Thanks a lot in advance.

EDIT:

ajax code:

```
function showData(dataType)
{

    var capa=document.getElementById("content");
    var ajax=nuevoAjax();
    capa.innerHTML="";
    ajax.open("POST", "test.php", true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.send("d="+dataType);

    ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (ajax.readyState==4)
        {
            capa.innerHTML=ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

In test.php is where I have the 4, 5 and 6 selectors in the same way I explained the 3. I also have this:

```
....
$dataType=$_POST['d'];

if($dataType=='1')
{
   //4 selectors
}elseif($dataType == '2')
{
  //5 selectors
}elseif($dataType == '3')
{
   //6 selectors
}
```

The div is updating properly and showing the correct layout (4,5 or 6 selects) but the code you gave me is not working. I´ve tried including the javascript in test.php and in landscape.php. No luck :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the PHP aside for this. You'll have a pure HTML page, once the PHP has done its thing, right? So the javascript simply has to interact with the DOM itself, as normal.

First, I wanted to store selected options for all the select elements, in an array. Doing this allows me to select an option in the first and the second color selectors, and have them BOTH disabled in the third.

Then, simply iterate over all the connected selects (I've connected them via a matching class), and within that iterate over all the selected options, and disable them as appropriate.

Sounds simple, but it was a bit of a challenge. More of a challenge (but not much more) might be to allow multi-selects.

Hope it helps, let me know if it needs a change.

```js
// This array will be used to store the current selection of
//   each connected select. They are connected by a class attr.
var selectedOption = new Array($(".colorSelector").length);

/*******
 * Any time any select is changed, we update the selectedOption
 *  array to include the new selection. Note that the array is
 *  the same length as the number of selects, and that we're
 *  setting the value to the position in that array that relates
 *  to the position of the element itself. By this, I mean that
 *  selectedOption[0] contains the value of select[0], 
 *  selectedOption[4] contains the value of select[4],
 *  and so on.
 *******/
$("body").on("change",".colorSelector", function() {
  // First, get the value of the selected option.
  selectedOption[$(this).index()] = $(this).val();

  /***
   * Now, we iterate over every connected select element.
   *  we want to disable all values that are selected in
   *  all other connected selects -- those values we've stored
   *  in the selectedOption array. As long as the value is
   *  not blank, or the default '...', or the current element,
   *  we disable that option.
   ***/
  $(".colorSelector").each(function() {
    // First, re-enable all options.
    $(this).children("option").removeAttr("disabled");
    // Iterate over the selectedOption list
    for (i = 0; i < selectedOption.length; i++) {
      if (selectedOption[i] != "" && selectedOption[i] != "..." && i != $(this).index()) {
        // Disable any option that isn't default, or
        //  ignore if the current selectedOption points to
        //  this select.
        $(this).children("option[value='" + selectedOption[i] + "']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="color1" id="color1" class="colorSelector">
  <option>...</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="indigo">Indigo</option>
  <option value="violet">Violet</option>
</select>
<select name="color2" id="color0" class="colorSelector">
  <option>...</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="indigo">Indigo</option>
  <option value="violet">Violet</option>
</select>
<select name="color3" id="color3" class="colorSelector">
  <option>...</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="indigo">Indigo</option>
  <option value="violet">Violet</option>
</select>
```

Also, this is up as a [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/rnzfv5ns/), just in case.

EDIT: You mention that this doesn't work when the select is populated by AJAX. You're exactly right, it didn't work as written. The reason is, when an element is loaded after the page has loaded, it doesn't automatically connect to the page's current listeners. Instead, I've changed where the listener is attached in the above code. Instead of listening like `$(".colorSelector").on("change"...)`, I've changed it to `$("body").on("change", ".colorSelector", function(){...});` -- note that the listener now gets attached to the body. Doing this causes any element with the `.colorSelector` class to trigger, whether it was there initially or added later. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Snowmonkey, thanks a lot for your awesome reply. The script is working fine but if I try to embed the functionality with AJAX, it doesn´t work. 

This is what I have: 
landscape.php: when it loads for the first time, I have 2 selectors with colors. Here it is working fine. 
I also have 3 buttons. When I click in any of then, the div containing the selectors changes to 3, 4 or 5 selectors depending on the button I clicked. When this happens, the colorSelector doesn't work. I will add the ajax code in the original message. Thanks

Comment: I've done this before myself, and it's _far more complicated_ than most people think.  Nice answer!

Comment: @saysmus, I've edited the code to handle that. Basically, when you add elements dynamically (whether AJAX or not), they do not inherit the listeners. Thus, I changed which element listens -- now the body element listens for any .colorSelector being changed, and should work with dynamically created elements.

Comment: @saysmus - you should upvote / accept - if it's not integrating with AJAX, that's a different problem.

Comment: Thanks, @cale_b, for your props. You're right, it actually took a little more skull sweat than I'd thought to get this working well. Fun one, though.

Comment: @Snowmonkey I upvoted but as I don't have reputation enough it didn't get reflected. Sorry about that. Didn't know about the accept thingy (quite new over here). Didn't have time to try your changes, I will do in a while. Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciated.

Comment: Hi again, I just tried the code and it is not working. Nothing happens. Not even an error message. I can select the same color in every single select. Let's leave it here as my real problem is what I specified in the other threat. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have this on a localhost, or is this live someplace where we can see it not working?